# Pooling for DbDataReader

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

We have a DbDataReader for connecting with SQL Server 2005 from our application. I would like to know how to set the following two for the DbDataReader

1)  Pooling = false

2)  Connection Timeout=0;

Please share your thoughts.

```
    DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("aspInsertZipCode");
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
    dataStringToProcess.Remove(dataStringToProcess.Length - 1, 1);

    db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@DataRows", DbType.String, dataStringToProcess.ToString());
    db.AddInParameter(cmd, "currDate", DbType.DateTime, DateTime.Now);
    db.AddInParameter(cmd, "userID", DbType.Int32, UserID);
    db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "CountOfUnchangedZipCode", DbType.String, 1000);

    DbDataReader rdr = null;

    try
    {

        rdr = (DbDataReader)db.ExecuteReader(cmd);
        if (rdr.Read())
        {

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Utility.GetString(rdr, "NewZipCode")))
                strNewZipCode = strNewZipCode + "," + Utility.GetString(rdr, "NewZipCode");

        }
        rdr.NextResult();
        if (rdr.Read())
        {

            strRetiredZipCode = strRetiredZipCode + "," + Utility.GetString(rdr, "RetiredZipCode");

        }

        int TempUnchageZipCount = Convert.ToInt32(db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "CountOfUnchangedZipCode"));
        CountOfUnchangedZipCode = CountOfUnchangedZipCode + TempUnchageZipCount;
        dataStringToProcess = new StringBuilder();
        cntRec = 0;

    }
    catch
    {
        if (rdr != null && (!rdr.IsClosed))
            rdr.Close();
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (rdr != null && (!rdr.IsClosed))
            rdr.Close();
    }
    cmd.Dispose();
```

Thanks

Comment: You know that `using(DbDataReader rdr = db.ExecuteReader(cmd)) {...}` would replace all of that messing with `null`/`try`/`catch`/`finally`/`Close()`/`Dispose()`/`IsClosed` right? Plus: you forgot to dispose the `cmd` ;p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connection pooling is handled by the specific provider. You're using a `DbConnection` which is the abstraction, but for instance, Sql Server handles connection pooling and timeout through the connection string, e.g.:

```
SERVER=127.0.0.1;Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=true;Timeout=0;Pooling=false;
```

What actually provider are you using?

On another note, what reason would you need for disabling Connection pooling and timeout? Both features are efficiency features which greatly improve how your app performs. By disabling these, and having some bad behaving code, you could end up with quite an unstable end solution, which hogs memory and may lead to unterminated connections....?

Comment: We are using Enterprise Library. I understand the shortcomings of the approach; however we need to test with pooling = false and Timeout 0 ----- Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("aspg");

Comment: Setting these values in connectionstring itself is one way.